# sequential space, KC space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

**Let $X$ be a topological space.**

A subset $U$ of $X$ is **sequentially open** if each sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ converging to a point of $U$ is eventually in $U$.

A subset $F$ of $X$ is **sequentially closed**  if, whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $F$ converging to $x$, then $x$ must also be in $F$.

(1):A **sequential space** is a space $X$ satisfying one of the following equivalent conditions:

Every sequentially open subset of $X$ is open.

Every sequentially closed subset of $X$ is closed.

(2):A **KC  space** is a space that every compact subset is closed.

> I have a question:
>
> **Is a compact, countable KC-space  sequential? Why?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, every compact, countable $KC$ space is sequential; this is Corollary $3$ in Ofelia T. Alas and Richard G. Wilson, [‘Spaces in which compact sets are closed and the lattice of $T_1$ topologies on a set’](http://emis.matem.unam.mx/journals/CMUC/pdf/cmuc0204/Alaswil.pdf), Comment. Math. Univ. Carolinae, $43$ ($2002$), $641$-$652$.

Comment: What does it mean "If A is not **closed**, then it is not **compact**." ?which relation does have with "Theorem 2" in that paper?

Comment: @fatemeh: Let $A$ be a subset of $X$ that isn’t closed. $X$ is $KC$, so $A$ is not compact. By Theorem $2$ there is a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $A$ converging to some $p\in X\setminus A$. This shows that $A$ is not sequentially closed. It follows that every sequentially closed set in $X$ is closed and hence that $X$ is sequential.